# Shadar-Kai Elf Bear Totem Barbarian Resistance

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, resistance, shadar-kai

If a player is a Shadar-Kai Elf and plays a Bear Totem Barbarian, would the raging damage type resistance stack with the Shadar-Kai teleport resistance?

Comment: What game is this about, D&D 5e? I think it is because that is the only one with a Path of the Totem Warrior: Bear class.